# Is there a way to bind an application to a second desktop in headless mode on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, virtual, windows-virtual-desktop

I need to create virtual display as

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/desktops

or

https://github.com/henkman/virgo

But i need create display in headless mode without switching my main, run application on second desktop , and make app bind to second desktop, like it my app want make screen he gonna screen my second desktop, not my main what im watching

Just make app think second desktop, its actual

or do i have write something in app ?